# Use an array in main() in another function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Hello I have a task to make a function that fills an array, made in main(), and then use the array in another function, where I should make some calculations with it. I already have some code, could you please assist me how to do it? Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

int* modArray(int* a, int size) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return a;
}

int modAddition() {} // This is the function, where I want to use, the "a" array

int main() {

    int size = 7;
    int* a = new int[size];

    a = modArray(a, size);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"how to do it"* How do do *what*? Your code already seems to pass the array to the function.

Comment: Also note that you don't need to return the `int *` in this case. You could change the return type to `void`, remove `return a;` and replace `a = modArray(a, size);` with `modArray(a, size);` without any change in behavior.

Comment: You already done it with `modArray`, do the same with `modAddition`

Comment: Well, thank you for the help, I thought that when I have an array in the main it is a local and I cannot use it in another function, with just typing int* a, because it is going to make a new array. I am still a beginner so that confused me.

Comment: You made the array when typing `new int[size]`. While `int* a =` just made a pointer. That pointer will point to the array's first element, and it will till point there even if you pass it to a function. The array itself will live until you call `delete[]` passing a pointer pointing to the array. Until then, you can use it from any function if you have a pointer or reference to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your modArray works, and the return steatment is not needed in this case. You can just do the same in your modAddition. Rembemer that if they don't have a return, they will be void methods.